# How do I start external Applications in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to be able to start External Application in C# WPF How do I do it?

Comment: The answer varies depending on what you want to do with your external app. Do you want to start it and load it as a sub-component to your main app (ie. to send it native C# events and such)? Do you want to setup pipes to talk a secondary process? Or do you just want to "fire and forget" an external EXE to do processing for you?

Comment: can you give me examples to all 3 please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`Process.Start("path/to/your/file")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: if you had followed the link to some of the overloads, there are fully working examples. Like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx#Y1319